# how to clean caulk between tub and tile

Tags: caulk

I am removing the caulk around the bathtub and tile. I believe the previous owner removed the grout out and filled the gap entirely with caulk.  I applied silicone remover which is helping but there is still residue that I cannot remove or scrape out of the gaps.

Comment: FYI, they likely didn't remove grout. You should never grout between two unlike surfaces (in this case tile and the tub). In other words, caulk is the proper filler between the tile and the tub.

Answer (score 3):

Removing caulking can be time consuming, especially in the bathroom. From my experience there is no magic solution.

I recommend these tools:

- flat head screw driver
- small paint scrapper (plastic as to not scratch any finishes)
- hair dryer

Using the hair dryer, heat up the caulking, then use paint scrapper to loosen the caulking by pushing on top and bellow, try to keep the caulk intact. Once you've freed one end, try to gently pull away following the line in which is was laid. Use the paint scrapper as you peel away and try to get long lengths to keep it clean.

The flat head screwdriver is if you have difficulty getting a started but usually the paint scraper will do the job.

If the caulking is dry, you will be using both the screw driver and paint scraper.

Patience is a must.

Comment: Just did this recently too.  There is no magical way to remove it unfortunately...its just one of those time consuming things that has to be done every once in a while.  A razor knife can also be useful.